# FB share button vs pasting link

Tags: facebook

I am experiencing a strange FB share behaviour. When I share the link with the "share" button it show a logo as a default picture. But when I paste a link into post, then it shows the correct image.

Do you have any ideas why it is like that?

Here is the link to the website where you can try it out ourself
http://www.slacklinefestivals.com/festival/545dbbeed7b93c0b009f2f88/9-chemnitzer-slackfest

Comment: I just tested this and the "Share" button is also showing the photo. In general for these issues, the solution can be to re-scrape your page (for example by using the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, or do it automated).

Comment: Here is an another example: http://www.slacklinefestivals.com/report/photo/55e446274bdc7411006f9781/bern-city-slack-6 that doesn't work. But the questions is why I see it correctly in the facebook share dialog, but not when it is actually shared, after pressing the share button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out!

So when you share the link and you are pasting it into a facebook post, the last picture is used as default.

If you are using a share button, it shows the last picture in the preview  - in the share dialog, but once you confirm it, **the the first picture is used**. e.g. the first picture with the meta tag `og:image`.

Well, this is super confusing I can tell you!